# Getting back a nonexistant url in test

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

So I have a django web app called notes where I have a viewset. The viewset is composed of CRUD commands. When I created a test to the api it keeps redirecting to a nonexistent url instead of the Json String. Here is my code:

For tests.py:

```
def test_list(self):
    e = Employee.objects.get(first_name="Dylan")
    organ = Organization.objects.get(name='test')
    cl = APIClient()
 #   cl = APIClient()
    c = Customer.objects.get(first_name="John")

    cl.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Token ' + organ.token.key)
    response = cl.post('/api/notes/list', {'customer_id': c.uuid}, follow=True)
    #cl.login(username = "Dylan", password="Snyder")

    pprint("list: %s" % response.data)
```

for api.py:

```
 def list(self, request):
    c = Customer.objects.get(pk=request.POST['customer_id'])

    n = Note.objects.get(customer=c, retired=False)
    notes = NoteListSerializer(n)

    return HttpResponse(notes)
```

The results I get:

```
.'list: {\'detail\': \'Method "GET" not allowed.\'}'
```

in the command prompt I use. I never made a directory or have anything that contains /details/ in it

Comment: Can you expain APIClient class? It seems your HTTP request is GET instead of POST.

Comment: The informations you provided don't match the error (sending a POST and getting an error with GET) which means you've altered too much the data. Please give accurate code and errors if you want help.

Comment: Can you post also the serializer NoteListSerializer ? Do you have any hyperlink fields?

Comment: Here is my serializer class:

class NoteListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Note
        fields = (
            'uuid', 'created_at', 'modified_at', 'employee', 'call-record', 'body')     @GabrielMuj

Comment: I have the post allowing to follow, which for some reason is sending it to a nonexisting URL

Comment: Okay so I just checked the Error_code and it is 405

Comment: @Dylan remove follow=True when doing cl.post , you don't do any redirect in the view. From the docs: If you set follow to True the client will follow any redirects and a redirect_chain attribute will be set in the response object containing tuples of the intermediate urls and status codes.